# Android Studio CalendarView mark dates

Tags: java, android-studio, calendar, android-calendar, calendarview

I am doing an app and I want to add a calendarView. I just want to mark some specific dates using the day, month and year. I founded MCalendarView library but I dont like the design.

Someone knows how to mark dates in regular CalendarView or improve the design of MCalendarView?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old topic and you have probably solved your problem since, but it might help other people. I found this library to mark different dates and even more with a design very similar to the default Android CalendarView. Hope this could help https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

**installation**

Add the JitPack repository to your build file

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

Add the dependency (do not forget to change the `${version}` with a valide version, just look for the library to https://jitpack.io and choose one)

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:${version}'
}
```

Now just call the view in you layout

```xml
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
    app:mcv_selectionColor="#00F"
    />
```

Documentation on how to use the api to customize the view is available [here](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/wiki/Customization)